# Rails: query for 2-step relation through join-table + has many relation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am working on improving my database scheme. Currently I use a has_many through structure with a land model/table a shippingservice model/table and a postzone model/table, which connects land and shipping tables.

[image: Has many through]

I can query this way:

```
@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.includes(:lands, :postzones).where('postzones.land_id = ?', params[:id])
```

And get all shipping services for a given land (country).

But this way I end up with a lot of repetition in the postzone table and maintenance is quite difficult. It would be much easier if I could collect lands in zones with many lands and than connect shipping services to a zone. Just like in this scheme:

[image: Join table + has many]

How would I query in this case for all shipping services for a given land?

For a join table I would do something like:

```
@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands => :zones).where('lands_zones_join.land_id = ?', params[:id])
```

Which does not work, since I get:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'lands_zones_join.zone_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `shippingservices`.* FROM `shippingservices` 
INNER JOIN `zones` ON `zones`.`id` = `shippingservices`.`zone_id` 
INNER JOIN `lands_zones` ON `lands_zones`.`zone_id` = `zones`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `lands` ON `lands`.`id` = `lands_zones`.`land_id` 
INNER JOIN `lands_zones` `zones_lands_join` ON `zones_lands_join`.`land_id` = `lands`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `zones` `zones_lands` ON `zones_lands`.`id` = `zones_lands_join`.`zone_id` 
WHERE (weightmin <= 50 AND weightmax >= 50 AND height >= 3 AND shippingservices.shippingcarrier = '1') AND (length >= 210 AND width >= 149) AND (lands_zones_join.zone_id = '2')
```

**Is this even possible?**  How can I get this to work?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

models/shippingservices.rb

```
class Shippingservice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zone
  has_many :lands, :through => :zone
end
```

app/models/zone.rb

```
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lands, :join_table => "lands_zones"
  has_many :shippingservices
end
```

app/models/landszone.rb

```
class LandsZone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :land
  belongs_to :zone
end
```

app/models/land.rb

```
class Land < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :zones, :join_table => "lands_zones"
  has_many :shippingservices, :through => :zones
end
```

db/schema.rb

```
create_table "lands", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "lands_zones", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "land_id"
  t.integer  "zone_id"
end

add_index "lands_zones", ["land_id"], :name => "index_lands_zones_on_land_id"
add_index "lands_zones", ["zone_id"], :name => "index_lands_zones_on_zone_id"

create_table "shippingservices", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "zone_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "shippingcarrier"
end

  create_table "zones", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

I reduced it by deleting timestamps, etc. but kept all necessary parts.

Comment: Can you add the actual code from each model and your schema.rb? I suspect that the join table is named `lands_zones` not `lands_zones_join`

Comment: @Tom thanks for your feedback. I added all data you requested. Although I used the same schema + query I have used for years, although only for a join tables and not for join-table + has many through.

Comment: `.where('lands_zones_join.land_id = ?', params[:id])` why are you querying for a table called `land_zones_join` here? `.where('lands_zones.land_id = ?', params[:id])` The schema and models look correct.

Comment: I used `.where('lands_zones_join.land_id = ?', params[:id])` for a join connection with the same model and schema configuration and it worked. Currently the associations are there, but I end up with double the shippingservices for a given land.

Comment: I've never seen the addition of `_join` to the end of a table name in a query before. Can you try `@cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(lands: {id: params[:id]})`?

Comment: Something is confusing the query. The last two joins appear to be joining on derived tables such as: `zones_lands.id` which may be causing the duplication.

Comment: `@cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(lands: {id: params[:id]})` works! Why does it work this way with `:id => params[:id]` in {}? If you could write your suggestion as an answer I would be happy to upvote it!

Comment: The use of the hash in the where clause is just syntactic sugar.  It is synonymous for: `where("lands.id = ?", params[:id])`. Also, Rails automatically escapes params in hash notation making both formats equally safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@shippingservices = @cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands => :zones).where('lands_zones_join.land_id = ?', params[:id])`

The `lands_zones_join` table in the where clause is incorrect. Rails is seeing this  as a derived table name and applying two extra joins seen here:

```
INNER JOIN `lands_zones` `zones_lands_join` ON `zones_lands_join`.`land_id` = `lands`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `zones` `zones_lands` ON `zones_lands`.`id` = `zones_lands_join`.`zone_id`
```

This is leading to the duplication in the query results.

The relations from `Shippingservice` to `Land` has been set up correctly in the models and schema.  We can therefore join the tables directly and query the lands table itself for the id:

`@cart.available_shipping_services.joins(:lands).where(lands: {id: params[:id]})`

Comment: how would I have to define the land_id in the query, when I am in a session? I found out that the query works in one direction, but does not keep the selection when going back in bowser. I described everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953658/rails-dynamic-select-on-multistep-form-not-keeping-selected Maybe you can point me into the right direction.